# When i Create table with Month he only given 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, date, dayofmonth

I create table for hour

```sql
CREATE TABLE hour (
    Name1 varchar(25) not null,
    Datee Datetime not null DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),
    Monthh date not null DEFAULT (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))
);
```

Mysql only give me 0000-00-00 not Name where i use button in php. What is wrong with this and how correct? In my opinion my phpadmin dont have a MONTH function

Comment: DATE datatype is wrong for the month number which is numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE hour ( Name1 varchar(25) not null,
                    Datee DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                    Monthh TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT (MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
                  );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58cc7b7c2e31f8acd7c2ddcfccc5b940)

PS. `HOUR` is [Reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-H) - I'd recommend to rename a table.

Comment: Name table is only for ask you. Real name is "Godzina". Polish langauge 

Answer (score 0):

Store full timestamp and it's month part in separate columns in same table is absolutely redundant. You can story only datetime and get it's month in select query:

```
CREATE TABLE Godzina (
  Nazwa varchar(25) not null,
  Randka Datetime not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);

INSERT INTO Godzina (Nazwa) VALUES ('TestName');

SELECT 
    Nazwa,
    Randka,
    MONTH(Randka) AS Miesiac
FROM Godzina;
```

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=a50dbc42b0996ff85e18d791377146b9&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Nothing prevents `Datee` in OP's structure to be changed in future whereas `Monthh` stay unchanged. Your solution is not applicable in such case.